# setting tocdepth to zero in report class makes minilot and minilof not show up

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I want my main TOC to only show chapters. Not sections and subsections. This is `report` class. So I added `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` which worked. But then I noticed something strange. `minilof` and `minilot` in my chapters are now all empty. But `minitoc` is not empty.

How can one make the main TOC shows only chapters, but still have a `minilot` and `minilof` in each chapter?  Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%   
\usepackage{minitoc}  
\begin{document}
\dominitoc  %initialize
\dominilof
\dominilot
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} %For the main TOC, only show chapter, but this
     %makes minilot not to show up ! change to 1 to have minilot show up!
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables        
ok....    
\chapter{chapter test}
\minitoc  %this show OK
\minilof  %this is empty
\minilot

here we go, one table, to see if it will show up in minilot

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{my table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
nice table\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\section{section below the chapter}
some section
\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdflatex, shows this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

changing `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` to `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` now it shows:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

question is: How to make main TOC only show chapters, but still be able to use `minilot` and `minilof`. Notice that there is no issue with `minitoc`.

Using TL 2015

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 minitoc.sty    2015/07/13 v61 Package minitoc
 mtcmess.sty    2006/03/14
     foo.mtc0
 english.mld    2006/01/13
 english.mld    2006/01/13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what is meant? Writing `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` to the `.toc` file and restoring this afterwards by using some default `level` (say `3`) in the `.lof` and `.lot` -- this assumes, that `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables` is used **after** `\tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%   
\usepackage{minitoc}  
\def\mytocdepth{3}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc  %initialize
\dominilof
\dominilot
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\mytocdepth}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\mytocdepth}}
%\setcounter{minitocdepth}{\mytocdepth} %For the main TOC, only show chapter, but this
     %makes minilot not to show up ! change to 1 to have minilot show up!
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables        
ok....    
\chapter{chapter test}
\minitoc  %this show OK
\minilof  %this is empty
\minilot

here we go, one table, to see if it will show up in minilot

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{my table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
nice table\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}

\section{section below the chapter}
some section
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works on MWE, but there is a HUGE problem. I found it fails when I include, guess what, the `\usepackage{breqn}` then I get many errors!.  `Undefined control sequence. \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` etc.. many syntax errors are generated when just adding the above package, which I have to have there. Very strange. If you know a workaround or why that happens. Or I could post separate question if needed. But as it stands, I can't use this solution at this moment because of this. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser: That's due to the fact that `\setcounter` is fragile. Use `\protect\setcounter{...}{...}` for the toc-writing, see my update please.