# tex4ht gives an error for code it is NOT supposed to look at! `\spacefactor' in vertical mode error

Tags: tex4ht

I have never seen anything like this before. I use some Latex code which works in pdf only. The code is surrounded by

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\else
  .... latex code which tex4ht is not supposed to use
\fi
```

I just found out that tex4ht gives an error due to the code it is not supposed to look at. How could this be possible?  The code is only supposed to run in pdf mode.  When I delete the code below the `\else`, tex4ht gives no error.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}%          
\ifdefined\HCode
\else
%thanks to solution from
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309244/how-to-show-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables-inside-chapters-only-and-not-also#309245
%this is meant only for pdf, not HTML.
\newif\ifshowlistof
\makeatletter
\def\@starttocbutdonotshowtoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{\mytocdepth}
    \ifshowlistof
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \fi
    \if@filesw
     \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
     \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
     \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
    \endgroup}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
  \@starttocbutdonotshowtoc{lot}%
}  
\makeatother
\fi        
\begin{document}           
test
\end{document}
```

now `pdflatex` gives no error. Since I know the code works in pdf. But compiling with tex4ht gives very strange error:

```
htlatex  foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) 
 (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./foo.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty)
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.19     \@
           nobreakfalse
?
```

TL 2015, on Linux.

Comment: You could try moving `\newif\ifshowlistof` out of the `\ifdefined\HCode` condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're compiling with `tex4ht`, the test `\ifdefined\HCode` returns true, so TeX wants to discard the false branch. So it goes from `\else` up to the matching `\fi` *without* expanding macros or executing commands, but matching conditionals.

Since `\ifshowlistof` is not a conditional when `\else` is scanned, it never becomes one, so the matching `\fi` is the one in the body of `\def\@starttocbutdonotshowtoc`. Note that neither `\makeatletter` is executed, so `@` is still an “other character”. The test `\if@filesw` returns false (because `\if` compares `@` and `f`) and finally `\@` where `\@nobreakspace` was intended raises the error.

Solution: never put `\newif` in conditional text. If you do

```
\newif\ifshowlistof
\ifdefined\HCode
\else
  ...
\fi
```

the code will work.